# With cacheduration set, is it possible to have the function still trigger

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, caching

If I have my cacheduration set to some value for my Web Service, is it possible to force the function to trigger?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could force it is to send a no-cache header to the server.

For information view the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute.cacheduration.aspx), specifically the remarks, quoted below.

> In addition, HTTP indicates that a
>   user agent (the browser or calling
>   application) should be able to
>   override server caching by setting the
>   "Cache-Control" to "no-cache". ASP.NET
>   applications, therefore, ignore cached
>   results when they find a "no-cache"
>   header.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pattern I typically use. If the item exists in the cache you use it otherwise you create it and store it in the cache:

```
Dim Obj = Cache("YourKeyHere")
Dim YourObj As DataSet
If Obj IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf Obj Is DataSet Then
    YourObj = DirectCast(Obj, DataSet)
Else
    YourObj = New DataSet()
    '...do your normal loading of your object here
    Cache.Insert("YourKeyHere", YourObj)
End If
```

If instead you want to be notified when your cache expires you can use the [onUpdateCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491414.aspx)

Comment: Well i was thinking more from the client side. Say im returning a list of values to populated a dropdownbox. If the want to get the latest values, is there a way to just refire the function? Or do i have to write a whole new function.